# When should you leave the significance level from a hypothesis test the same as the confidnce interval and when must you change it

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

When you follow up a hypothesis test with a confidence interval sometimes you must change the significance level so the results match. When can you leave the significance level from the hypothesis test the same as the confidnce interval and when must you change the significance level from the hypothesis test. Explain using examples

Comment: If the two methods disagree it is usually because they are adopting different approaches to the problem so you need to give us a concrete example which is bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might need to detail further your question...

The significance level (alpha) reflects the level before you reject the hull hypothesis. Usually it is set to 0.05 but it needs to be adapted to your study. Here is, what I believe, is a clear and simple explanation
https://statisticsbyjim.com/glossary/significance-level/

For confidence interval, we are talking about confidence level, usually 0.95, which corresponds to the confidence we have to find our true population parameter falling into our calculated interval.